# java.sql.Timestamp to String with microsecond precision

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I am reading a timestamp column from the database into a java.sql.Timestamp object. Then I would like to convert the value of the timestamp to a String object but keep the microsecond precision. Calling toString() method gets me close but it seems to lose trailing zeros in the microsecond. If the timestamp ends in a non-zero number, everything is fine.

Sample:

```
SimpleDateFormat outDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
String s = "2005-02-25 11:50:11.579410";
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(s);
String out = ts.toString(); // This returns 2005-02-25 11:50:11.57941
out = outDateFormat.format(ts); // This returns 2005-02-25 11:50:11.000579
```

I am really looking to print 2005-02-25 11:50:11.579410.

Comment: `S` is a millisecond and not a microsecond...

Comment: Agreed. I put in the sample just to show how it behaves.

Comment: Why do you need microsecond precision?

Comment: I am replicating data between different database systems and timestamp precision must be preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the getNanos()-methode of Timestamp.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.");
String s = "2005-02-25 11:50:11.579410";
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(s);
int microFraction = ts.getNanos() / 1000;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fmt.format(ts));
String tail = String.valueOf(microFraction);
for (int i = 0; i < 6 - tail.length(); i++) {
    sb.append('0');
}
sb.append(tail);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Probably better to use `String.format` or even better a `MessageFormat` rather than the custom appending code.