# java.sql.Timestamp to Microseconds (Long with precision till Microseconds)

Tags: java, sql, scala, jdbc, timestamp

I have already looked at question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748449/java-sql-timestamp-to-string-with-microsecond-precision) and its solution, but looks like solution is from 2013 and I am looking for better solution than this.

How to convert DateTime(TimeStamp) from Oracle to Long with precision till Microseconds?

**For. e.g:** 
Timestamp coming from Oracle is: "2018-10-31 14:30:12.123456". I need it to convert it to Long: 1541010612123456.

```
I/P: "2018-10-31 14:30:12.123456" // String
O/P: 1541010612123456 // Long
```

I tried

```
java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-31 14:30:12.123456").getTime
```

But this give me precision till milliseconds: 1541010612123

To get around this I tried something like this, which works but not sure if its a good solution or not.

```
val timeStamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-31 14:30:12.123456").toInstant
val requiredLong = (timeStamp.getEpochSecond.toString + (timeStamp.getNano/1000).toString).toLong
```

Any better suggestion or solution.

Comment: Consider using `LocalDateTime` instead of `Timestamp`.

Comment: yeah, I am going to do that.

Comment: Better if you can retrieve either an `OffsetDateTime`, an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime` from Oracle and avoid the outdated and confusing `Timestamp` class completely. With a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver it should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TimeUnit for this conversion:

```
Instant instant = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-31 14:30:12.123456").toInstant();  
long micros = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(instant.getEpochSecond()) + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(instant.getNano());
```

Comment: If you cannot avoid the `Timestamp` class (and the risk of time zone trouble that comes with it), this is definitely the good solution. It’s clear to read, and it avoids loss of precision.